# I'm having difficulty with this limit. Lim as x approaches 2: [(1/x-2)-(4/x^2-4)]

Tags: limits

Consider the limit

$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{1}{x-2} - \frac{4}{x^2-4}$$

I just need help with the implementation of this limit. Is the best way of solving it to multiply out the fraction?

So,$$ \frac{x^2-4-4(x-2)}{(x-2)(x^2-4)}$$

And if that's the case... where do I go from there?

I'm sorry if this is extremely elementary!

Comment: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}\left[\frac{1}{x-2} - \frac{4}{x^2-4}\right]$$ is the limit you want?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't have it formatted well.

Comment: No worries. Just hover over my comment and click view latex (I believe) and then see how i format and then edit your post. Also check out the mathjax page on meta [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Good luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to2} \frac{1}{x-2} - \frac{4}{x^2-4}&= \lim_{x\to2} \frac{x+2 -4}{x^2-4}\\&= \lim_{x\to2} \frac{x-2}{(x-2)(x+2)}\end{align} $$

I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Yes I can, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you get the indeterminant form $\infty -\infty$, when you try to plug in $2@, subtract the two fractions and simplify.